# Running CMD commands from JAVA

Tags: java, cmd, command

I made this code to move a folder then hardlink it to it's original destination. The problem it works fully when I'm just trying it from eclipse but when I make it into it's own self executing jar it wont create the hardlink but it will move the folder. The code runs a command line and then enters the commands. I dont know ehy the move command works and not the other one. Please help.
(Mklink command)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class The_Cloud_Setup {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            String command = "c:\\cmd.exe";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , e.getMessage(), "End Result", 2);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        String[] StringMove = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "move"+" "+"\"C:/Users/%username%/Documents/My Games/Terraria/Players\""+" "+"\"C:/Users/%username%/Google Drive/Players\""};
        String[] StringMklink = {"cmd.exe", "/c",  "mklink"+" "+"/d"+" "+"\"C:/Users/%username%/Documents/My Games/Terraria/Players\""+" "+"\"C:/Users/%username%/Google Drive/Players\""};
        Process ProcessMove = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(StringMove);
        Process ProcessMklink = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(StringMklink);
        BufferedReader VarMove = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ProcessMove.getInputStream()));
         BufferedReader VarMklink = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ProcessMklink.getInputStream()));
        String temp = "";
        while ((temp = VarMove.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        VarMove.close();
        VarMklink.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start variable names with a lowercase character, according to the Java conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, when you are running natively, the move command has not completed before your program attempts to execute the mklink command.  You can't make a link where there is an existing folder.

Comment: Yes and no I just folded it into an exe that I can run as admin and bam it worked but thanks anyway